# Creating a Guice-instantiated parameterized Singleton

Tags: guice

For my purposes, I need certain classes (`SomeClass` and `SomeOtherClass` in the code below) to be instantiated by Guice (with default constructor or using @Inject, not through explicitly declaring a new instance or a builder) and for them to be a Singleton. The classes are also parameterized. I'm not too familiar with how Guice works. From my search, I have to do a bind as well as use a TypeLiteral - will the following code work for injecting the Singleton instance of `SomeClass` into `GuiceInstantiatedClass`?

```
public class SomeClassAbstract<T> {}

// <T> will always be type String 
public class SomeClass<T> extends SomeClassAbstract<T> {}

// <T> will always be type SomeOtherType
public class SomeOtherClass<T> extends SomeClassAbstract<T> {}

public class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<SomeClass<String>>() {}).asEagerSingleton();
        bind(new TypeLiteral<SomeOtherClass<SomeOtherType>>() {}).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}

public class GuiceInstantiatedClass {
    private final SomeClass<String> someClass;

    @Inject
    public GuiceInstantiatedClass(final SomeClass<String> someClass) {
        this.someClass = someClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it ought to work. But three things.  1) It's more common to use lazy singletons. `.as(Singleton.class);`  creates the singleton at first injection. So if the injector doesn't happen to need one (even with the module is installed), it won't be created. 2) By binding concrete classes rather than interfaces to implementations, you're missing out on the possibility of binding fakes in tests. You're limited to mocks. 3) `new com.google.inject.Key<SomeClass<String>>() {}`  is lighter-weight than `TypeLiteral`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use Key instead of TypeLiteral. For point 1, these classes will be used at every call to my service, which is a high TPS service, so I'm not worried about them not being used. Wouldn't it help from a latency perspective for the first call to instantiate them as eager Singletons? For point 2, are you saying that I should do `bind(new Key<SomeClassAbstract<String>>() {}).asEagerSingleton();` instead, and inject `SomeClassAbstract<String>` into GuiceInstantiatedClass? If that works, that would work as well for my use case.

Comment: You'd declare an interface `SomeInterface`, have `SomeClass` implement `SomeInterface`. Then say `bind(SomeInterface.class).to(SomeClass.class).in(Singleton.class);` and inject the interface. Now in tests you can say `bind(SomeInterface.class).to(FakeSomeClass.class);`, which is impossible if injecting concrete classes directly. (Note I'm skipping the type param here to fit in a comment.)

Comment: Hi Gene, thanks for all your help. :) I was wondering if it was necessary to create the interface, or could I use the abstract class? I was thinking something like: `bind(new Key<SomeClassAbstract<String>>() {}).to(new Key<SomeClass<String>>() {}).asEagerSingleton();` and then I can just @inject `SomeClassAbstract<String>` to the classes that use it. Is that an accepted and working implementation?